# Calculus 3 - directional deriviative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I recieved the following question:

Calculate the directional deriviative at the point (0,0), of the function:
$f(x,y) = x^{2}y + xe^{(x-y)}$

and in a direction that is tangent to the curve:

$x^{2}y + xe^{(x-y)}  = 3$ at the point $(1,1)$

Now.. more than a way to get to the answer I would love
an explanation of how should i attack this question, a set of
steps I should take.

Comment: As stated, the problem is nonsensical, because there is no tangent to the curve $x^2y + xe^{x-y} = 3$ at $(1,1)$. The point $(1,1)$ does not lie on that curve ($1^2\cdot 1 + 1\cdot e^{0-0} = 1 + 1 \ne 3$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question does not make sense since $x^{2}y + xe^{x-y}  \not= 3$ when $(x,y)=(1,1)$
Generally your steps toward such a question should be: 
First, find the partial derivative:$$f_x=2xy+e^{x-y}+xe^{x-y},f_y=x^2-xe^{x-y}$$
Plug in (1,1), we get $$f_x=2+1+1=4,f_y=1-1=0$$Then find the unit vector $\mathbf u$ in the direction.
Now use this formula to get the directional derivatives:$$D_{\vec u}f(x, y) = f_x(x, y)u_1 + f_y(x, y)u_2$$

Comment: Great, that's excatly what i've needed!